# routes with react-router-dom opens in parent container

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to work with react-router-dom but I can't understand how do I define a "main" container that will open all the other components inside ?
in the old version I used to do

```
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={ShowsPage} />

      <Route path="/shows" component={ShowsPage} />
      <Route path="/tickets" component={ticketsPage} />
    </Route>

    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
  </Router>
```

and it would work like magic, now I tried something like this

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route component={Main}/>
        <Route path="/" exact component={ShowsPage}/>
        <Route path="/tickets" exact component={ticketsPage}/>
        <Route path="/shows" exact component={ShowsPage}/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

I'm not sure how to implement the notfound routes, but in my last attempt to handle the routes I managed to make them open inside the container but I do get also this warning `` The prop `children` is marked as required in `Main`, but its value is `undefined `` and I wonder why I get them ? what do I do wrong ? and how can I set that every other route(beside whats defined) will be redirected to "/" (to ShowsPage component)

here is Main.js (my main container)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import HeaderContainer from './HeaderContainer';
import FooterContainer from './FooterContainer';

const Main = ({children}) => (
    <div>
        <container className="containerHeader">
            <HeaderContainer />
        </container>
        <container className="containerMain">
            {children}
        </container>
        <container className="containerFooter">
            <FooterContainer />
        </container>
    </div>
)

Main.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}


export default Main;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to show `ShowsPage`,`ticketsPage` and `ShowsPage` inside of `Main` component.
You have to put these component route inside of `Main` component

Add `history` prop to `Router`

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

Move the child component route inside of main(parent) component.

```
const Main = ({ match }) => { //assume main component.
    return (<div>
        This is the Root component.
        <Route path={`${match.url}`} exact component={ShowsPage} ></Route>
        <Route path={`${match.url}tickets`} exact component={ticketsPage}></Route>
        <Route path={`${match.url}shows`} exact component={ShowsPage}></Route>
    </div>)
};
```

Comment: Awesome! it works, but how can I change the route programmatically now (lets say I wanna switch the route from `ticketsPage`  to `ShowsPage` ?
thanks a lot!

Comment: means redirection?

Answer (score 2):

```
<Route component={Main}/>
<Route path="/" exact component={ShowsPage}/>
<Route path="/tickets" exact component={ticketsPage}/>
<Route path="/shows" exact component={ShowsPage}/>
```

should be

```
<Route component={Main} />
```

Add Route in the render method of Main.Place them inside a Switch (import from react-router-dom) like this

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/" exact component={ShowsPage}/>
 <Route path="/tickets" exact component={ticketsPage}/>
 <Route path="/shows" exact component={ShowsPage}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: now i get 2 warnings, ```Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored``` and ```Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Main`, but its value is `undefined`.```

Comment: try with the updated answer and let me know if it works

Comment: did you mean it like that ? https://pastebin.com/UNNmqHdU if yes I still get ```Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'children' is marked as required in 'Main', but its value is 'undefined'``` and when I try to change to url to something which isn't defined I get the Main component only without the ShowsPage component inside. beside everything works well (as I achieved to do with my first attempt as I showed up). thanks @RaviTeja Teja

Comment: add Switch at inside <container className="containerMain">, also don't make children as required